# Unable to connect Bitbucket Cloud (Beta) in Aws codepipeline

Tags: aws-codepipeline, bitbucket-cloud

Present i am working on integrate the  bitbucket cloud and aws codepipeline. i am not able to find the customer  bitbucket cloud repository's in aws codepipeline sourcecode provider. Normal repository's we are able to execute, but customer repository's only we are not able to select.

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks,
Balu

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686602/im-trying-to-integrate-bitbucket-into-aws-code-pipeline-what-is-the-best-appro

Answer (score 0):

The best way to integrate Bitbucket with any AWS Service is to use Pipelines to mirror any commit into a (mirror) AWS CodeCommit repo. then,you have prime integration into any service on AWS. You can find how to do it [here](https://medium.com/@jay_proulx/aws-codecommit-from-atlassian-bitbucket-and-bitbucket-pipelines-for-ci-offloading-4f1131695802)

Also, Check below posted earlier in StackOverflow :

[I'm trying to integrate Bitbucket into AWS Code Pipeline? What is the best approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686602/im-trying-to-integrate-bitbucket-into-aws-code-pipeline-what-is-the-best-appro)