# How to deploy an existing war file to AWS using bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I am creating a java web application and using bitbucket as my code repository. And I have an AWS instance (Running in Ubuntu) in which I host my web application under an apache tomcat application server.

I want to automatically deploy my war file to the webapp folder in tomcat (tomcat directory is something like home/ubuntu/etc/etc)

I know that it is possible to automate war file deployments to AWS using bitbucket and I tried various tutorials and instructions, but it didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to integrate Bitbucket into AWS Code Pipeline? What is the best approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686602/im-trying-to-integrate-bitbucket-into-aws-code-pipeline-what-is-the-best-appro)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using the [rsync-deploy](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/rsync-deploy/src/master/) pipe is the way to go. The pipe will sync your war file to the destination folder on your tomcat server. This is an example of the pipeline configuration:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.4.1
            variables:
              USER: 'username'
              SERVER: 'server-hostname'
              REMOTE_PATH: '/deploy-directory-name/'
              LOCAL_PATH: 'application.war'
```